# How can I change favicon. icon in magento 2

Tags: magento2, favicons

How can I change favicon.icon in magento 2 from backend?

I check it in **Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Design**
no option there?

Comment: The favicon is only correct for all pages except for my homepage? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRSex.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRSex.png) The homepage favicon is still magento favicon?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do this through the admin:

> Content -> Design -> Configuration

Select your theme,

[image]

Go to HTML Head

Set Favicon icon

Comment: Changing favicon from admin reflects in both frontend and admin end while changing it manually `/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Theme/web/favicon.ico` reflects only on front end.

Answer (score 8):

You can change favicon from admin panel

> 1. **go to Content -> Design -> Configuration**
> 2. **Click on HTML Head settings tab**
> 3. **Upload your favicon and save configuration.**

Make sure that you are editing this settings to the current active theme of your store

Answer (score 3):

I followed the [1st method in this tutorial to change favicon of Magento 2](https://magentip.com/how-to-change-favicon-of-magento-2-website/). You can try which you want.

There are 2 ways to change favicon of Magento 2 website

**Method 1 : Changing Favicon via backend (recommended)**

Log in to your Magento 2 backend, navigate to Store > Setting > Configuration > HTML Head
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDqXZ.jpg]

**Method 2: Changing Favicon in theme file (not recommended)**
You can also manually change Favicon of your Magento 2 store by upload and replace favicon.ico file located in

```
/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Theme/web/favicon.ico
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why do you not recommend method 2 btw? I like this method as it offers a fallback, say if someone makes a mistake with the favicon in the admin.

Comment: If using **Method 2** make sure you clear static files cache under `System/Cache Management => Flush Static Files Cache` button on the bottom. But **Method 1** is much easier and automatically displays the favicon on the frontend without having to flush the static files for just one favicon file. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem like a reason to "not recommend" the approach. Method 2 has a wide range of benefits over Method 1. It works for multi-environment setup (localhost / staging / production). In addition to the point @BenCrook makes. If following practice of not making changes on production first, this is the way to go.

Comment: Method 2 does not even work for me. I have a custom theme extending Magento/blank.
The favicon.ico does not even exist anywhere to override from your theme.

Answer (score 1):

Ok perhaps this is easier:

1. Create a Favicon
2. Upload the Favicon to Your Magento 2 Store
3. Refresh the Cache...
4. On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores.
5. Under Settings, choose Configuration.
6. In the panel on the left under General, choose Design.
7. Expand the HTML Head section.
8. Upload the favicon.

   1. Choose File.
   2. Then, find the favicon file that you prepared
   3. If you want to delete the current favicon, mark the Delete Image checkbox.
9. When complete, tap Save Config; Refresh the Cache
10. When prompted to refresh the cache

    1. Click the Cache Management link in the message at the top of the workspace.
    2. In the list, mark the Page Cache checkbox that is marked “Invalidated.”
    3. Set Actions to “Refresh.”
    4. Then, tap Submit

Comment: I've submitted a suggested edit for your answer, to make it into a step-by-step list. Could you check my edit to make sure I haven't made the information incorrect? (Also, you can read the [tour] to get a badge!)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 done

Comment: in  Magento 2  to **Content -> Design -> Configuration**  and  select the theme and Expand the HTML Head section..

Comment: @GokulK yes that's correct here if you're still having trouble I found this video the will guide you Step by step I looked it up just for you https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9J3rSgIJHrM

Comment: @sguzmanr in Magento 1.x in the  **General -> Design**  and in Magento 2.x to **Content -> Design -> Configuration**

Answer (score -2):

Use Firefox and Adblock to show open blockable items[image: open blockable items] and it'll give you the path(URL) to every element that loads with your website [image: to every element that loads with your website] it's easier this way when u want to change more than the favicon(from within your cpanel when you view your files you will know where to look bc you already know the path (folder)  to the file you want to change it helps when you want to modify your template bc it loads all the urls hopefully this helps

Comment: I think this is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: Sorry I thought it would be useful if he's customizing the website since he's changing the Favicon, I thought this would make things easier but in any case I added another answer that might be less confusing

Comment: Not only is this not what OP is asking, it is incorrect advice. Magento 2 deploys static resources to `pub/static`, but are housed elsewhere prior to deployment. This advice here hints towards editing those files directly (which I've seen junior developers attempt to do). Such changes would get blown away.